# List and quotes doesn't work with elementor post content widget

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm building a post content page using elementor but then I realize my post element such as quotes and list in wordpress post editor doesn't work on elementor post content widget, I already try search for this problem but a lot of topic is not about post content instead of post blog list.

this is what I want to achieve in my elementor post content widget:

[this is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWGRL.png)

[this is what I got now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG5MN.png)

this is another example:

[this is list what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA0zk.png)

[the list doesn't work on elementor post content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdTRo.png)

can someone help me to solve this problem? I can't figure what I'm wrong in here

Comment: You should add custom css to the post widget in advance tab of elementor widget settings. Add a class and add rest like .your-class ul{ list-style : disc} etc

Comment: thankyou for the response, I'm trying to use your approach and it success for the quotes but how can I make the list appear?

Comment: I'm using `list-style-type: disc;` but the bullet doesn't appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can use „selector” to target the wrapper element (inside the Post Content custom CSS if you got the Pro version)

```
selector li{
   list-style-type: disc;
   margin-left: 20px;
   margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using a workround way, You can style this inside a custom CSS or your customize wordpress since the html itself still read the tag but not appear so you must declare it such as:

```
.your-class your-tag{
   property: value;
}
```

the easiest example is like this:

```
.blog-class li{
   list-style-type: disc;
   margin-left: 15px;
   margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Don't give units as vw, use px like 20px is enough. Or depending on screen marginleft will be a lot

Comment: but isn't `px` unit not responsive in different screen size?

Comment: Yes, It's a fixed value. It won't change on responsiveness

Comment: thank you, I tried it and `px` quite stable when you already make the container itself responsive

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom CSS to solve this issue

```
.elementor-widget-container ul {
list-style: disc;
margin-left: 40px;}
```

You can adjust padding as per your requirement / design